# Programmatically making an emergency call on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'd like to make a button with which the user can dial through to emergency services.

There doesn't seem to be any specific method to call to do this, so I think I have to use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

and assign the phoneNumber myself. However, while I know this is 911 in the US, 999 in England, etc I'm not sure how to determine what country the user is in - I can retrieve their locale, but if they set their locale manually or travel outside their country, it wouldn't be reliable. I can resolve their location, but it won't work if they've turned off GPS or don't have internet connectivity.

I've heard 112 is now a universal standard on GSM phones - will it work on all iPhones?

Comment: Testing this feature should be interesting...

Comment: seems like 112 works at least in most countries: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/112_(emergency_telephone_number))

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure on how to obtain the different numbers, but assuming you have a set of these (let's say a dictionary by country), then you can use the network information on deciding which country the phone is currently located in.

You can do that by using the CoreTelephony framework, specifically the `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` and `CTCarrier` classes. Here's a small sample that will obtain the ISO 3166-1 country code of the current carrier.

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *network = [[[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init] autorelease];
CTCarrier *carrier = [network subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *countryCode = [carrier isoCountryCode];
```

Now `countryCode` will have the code (to my knowledge the Alpha-2 code), that is unique for each country, [here's a list of these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes)

Comment: This seems to retrieve the phone's home network information - I have a US phone (with a US SIM) and am currently in the UK, and it keeps retrieving US for the country code, as well as 310 (USA) for the mobile country code.

Comment: Also, after looking into it - as 112 is a GSM standard, I'm not sure if it will work with CDMA phones like the Verizon/Sprint iPhones...I may just tell the user to close the app and dial 911 to avoid sticky situations  :)

Comment: My mistake, I didn't read through the docs, 'subscriberCellularProvider' does indeed return the home network.

Answer (score 0):

> There doesn't seem to be any specific method to call to do this, so I
>   think I have to use
>
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:phoneNumber]];

This is correct.

Regarding what number to dial, I don't think there is a global emergency number.