# Current country's emergency telephone numbers using location

Tags: ios, location, telephony

I have been trying to find an API which gives the current country's emergency contact number **(i.e. for US 911, India 100,101,102)**.

Is there any way to get [the emergency call number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emergency_telephone_numbers) using my current location?

I already checked [Programmatically making an emergency call on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573502/programmatically-making-an-emergency-call-on-iphone), but it does not return the current county's emergency number.

Comment: I believe that on an iPhone you can call 911 or 112 anywhere and the phone will place an emergency call.

Comment: Nope I am in the India and I tried 911 it says call failed.

Comment: Ok.  Maybe it depends on the carrier.  It works for me in Australia where the emergency number is 000.  You should be able to call 112 on any GSM network globally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically making an emergency call on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573502/programmatically-making-an-emergency-call-on-iphone)

Comment: @Azat It will not work. It retrieves the home network information. Please check the answer/comment before post.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in Cocoa Touch to get such information based on user's location